# Calling derived class override method from generic reference in C#

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, polymorphism, virtual-functions

I'm building a game and there is basic inheritance hiearchy:

`GameObject` is a base class, has a virtual method called `Clone`

`PlatformObject` is derived from `GameObject`, overriding the `Clone` method

I have a serializer/deserializer generic class for any `GameObject` or derivations defined as below:

`public class XmlContentReaderBase<T> where T : GameObject`

My XML Reader class is unaware of my derived type. I've got a problem with this line:

```
        T obj = serializer.Deserialize(input) as T;
        return obj.Clone() as T;
```

The first line runs fine, and returns a `PlatformObject` which is correct. But the second line calls the `Clone` method of the base class, `GameObject`, which is not what I want. I need to call `PlatformObject.Clone` method, how can I get this done?

Thanks,
Can.

Comment: Can you add some code where your serialize GameObject ? Why are you reinventing XML serialization ?

Comment: Please post the code of the `Clone` methods (base and override).  If the runtime type of `obj` is in fact `PlatformObject` then the `PlatformObject` override should be called, not the base method.  If the base method is being called then your code is probably incorrect.

Comment: ok, while copying the code for posting, i realized that i was using the new keyword instead of override, and returning a PlatformObject instead of GameObject (that's why i was using GameObject).

problem solved now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote an implementation very close to this and see Clone referencing the derived object's Clone method (cheated a bit by creating a new object rather than deserializing one).

Post more code?

```
using System.Text;

namespace GenericExperiment
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XmlContentReaderBase<PlatformObject>.Deserialize();
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }

    class GameObject : ICloneable
    {
        object ICloneable.Clone()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("I am the base class");
            return null;
        }
    }

    class PlatformObject: GameObject, ICloneable
    {
        object ICloneable.Clone()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("I am the derived class");
            return null;
        }
    }

    class XmlContentReaderBase<T> where T : GameObject, new()
    {
        static public object Deserialize()
        {
            T obj = new T();
            ((ICloneable)obj).Clone();
            return obj;
        }
    }

}
```

Output:

> I am the derived class

Comment: no, i am not using the IClonable interface. Clone is the virtual method of GameObject

Comment: ok, while copying the code for posting, i realized that i was using the new keyword instead of override, and returning a PlatformObject instead of GameObject (that's why i was using GameObject). problem solved now.

Comment: There you go :-)  Glad you could resolve it.  On a side note, I would not recommend calling something Clone if it doesn't implement the ICloneable contract, as that may cause confusion for yourself or someone else down the road.  Maybe call it Copy or similar if you don't want to implement ICloneable.

Comment: yeah you are right, it may lead to confusion, i'll probably change it to copy or something :)